# How to pass null value to a field based on conditional value of another field

Tags: jolt

I have a field named xyz which is a radio button which has values YES/NO. When value NO is selected I want to send a null to a multiple keys. Any pointers to achieve the same?

Comment: Can you please give a concrete example in order to reproduce the desired case.